# Mocking node module in Detox test

Tags: react-native, testing, jestjs, e2e-testing, detox

Is it possible to mock a node_module using guide provided here: https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Guide.Mocking.md

I was able to mock a regular file, but is it also possible for node modules? If so, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

To mock a third party module with detox, you need to create some sort of a proxied module. Then you can create a mock-version of that file which detox then can pick up for testing.

In my case I wanted to mock expo-tracking-transparency.

1. I created my proxy file `expo-tracking-transparency.ts` which just exports again what the package expo-tracking-transparency itself exports:

```
export * from 'expo-tracking-transparency';
```

2. Next to this file (in the same folder) I created a mock-File `expo-tracking-transparency.mock.ts` which mocks the functions I need:

```
- src/helpers
       |__ expo-tracking-transparency.ts
       |__ expo-tracking-transparency.mock.ts
```

```
import { PermissionResponse, PermissionStatus } from 'expo-tracking-transparency';

const response: PermissionResponse = {
  status: PermissionStatus.DENIED,
  granted: false,
  expires: 'never',
  canAskAgain: true,
};

const requestTrackingPermissionsAsync = (): Promise<PermissionResponse> => Promise.resolve(response);

const getTrackingPermissionsAsync = (): Promise<PermissionResponse> => Promise.resolve(response);

export { requestTrackingPermissionsAsync, getTrackingPermissionsAsync };
```

3. Now, to make the magic happen (=to make detox pick up the mock-file instead of the helper-file), you need to run metro with the `--sourceExts`-option where you set mock-extensions before your normal file extensions like so:

```bash
react-native start --sourceExts mock.ts,mock.js,js,json,ts,tsx
```

With Metro running start your detox tests and it should pickup your mock-files if they are present.